# How to separate a String inside the list into Sub string without create a new list in python

Tags: python, string, list, loops, split

i have python list,

```
l=['wright_2035566_qwerty , wright_2035566_qwerty,wright_2035566_qwerty']
```

but i needed this list into that format in python required list

```
new_list=['wright_2035566_qwerty', 'wright_2035566_qwerty', 'wright_2035566_qwerty']
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use:

```
new_list = list(map(str.strip, l[0].split(',')))
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works for you:

```
new_list = [x.strip() for x in l[0].split(',')]
```